# access xslt elements from codebehind

Tags: xslt, code-behind

How can i set value(in code  behind) for an element declared in the xslt ?
Here is my xslt

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Header/Item">
      <td class="rowHead" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
        <a href="#">
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>aColumnText</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
            <xsl:text>showPopWin('UploadFile_Step4_Modal.aspx?ColumnNumber=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
            <xsl:text>',500,500,returnParameters);</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
        <input type="text" name="hiddenColumnValue">
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>hiddenColumnValue</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </input>
        <input type="text" name="hiddenColumnNumber">
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>hiddenColumnNumber</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </input>
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Now i have to set the value of hiddenColumnValue in the codebehind, how can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create asp.net markup with xslt](http://www.muonlab.com/web-development/create-aspnet-markup-from-xml-and-xslt/)